# TfidfVectorizer model loaded from joblib file only works when trained in same session

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nltk, joblib, tfidfvectorizer

`sklearn...TfidfVectorizer` only works when it is applied just after it is trained, when the analyzer returns a list of `nltk.tree.Tree` objects. This is a mystery because **the model always loaded from a file** before being applied. Debugging shows nothing wrong or different about the model file when it is loaded and applied at the start of its own session, vs. when trained in that session. The analyzer is also applied and working correctly in both cases.

Below is a script to help reproduce the mysterious behavior:

```
import joblib
import numpy as np
from nltk import Tree
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

def lexicalized_production_analyzer(sentence_trees):
    productions_per_sentence = [tree.productions() for tree in sentence_trees]
    return np.concatenate(productions_per_sentence)

def train(corpus):
    model = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer=lexicalized_production_analyzer)
    model.fit(corpus)
    joblib.dump(model, "model.joblib")

def apply(corpus):
    model = joblib.load("model.joblib")
    result = model.transform(corpus)
    return result

# exmaple data
trees = [Tree('ROOT', [Tree('FRAG', [Tree('S', [Tree('VP', [Tree('VBG', ['arkling']), Tree('NP', [Tree('NP', [Tree('NNS', ['dots'])]), Tree('VP', [Tree('VBG', ['nestling']), Tree('PP', [Tree('IN', ['in']), Tree('NP', [Tree('DT', ['the']), Tree('NN', ['grass'])])])])])])]), Tree(',', [',']), Tree('VP', [Tree('VBG', ['winking']), Tree('CC', ['and']), Tree('VP', [Tree('VBG', ['glimmering']), Tree('PP', [Tree('IN', ['like']), Tree('NP', [Tree('NNS', ['jewels'])])])])]), Tree('.', ['.'])])]),
 Tree('ROOT', [Tree('FRAG', [Tree('NP', [Tree('NP', [Tree('NNP', ['Rose']), Tree('NNS', ['petals'])]), Tree('NP', [Tree('NP', [Tree('ADVP', [Tree('RB', ['perhaps'])]), Tree(',', [',']), Tree('CC', ['or']), Tree('NP', [Tree('DT', ['some'])]), Tree('NML', [Tree('NN', ['kind'])])]), Tree('PP', [Tree('IN', ['of']), Tree('NP', [Tree('NN', ['confetti'])])])])]), Tree('.', ['.'])])])]
corpus = [trees, trees, trees]
```

First train the model and save the `model.joblib` file.

```
train(corpus)
result = apply(corpus)
print("number of elements in results: " + str(result.getnnz()))
print("shape of results: " + str(result.shape))
```

We print the number of results `.getnnz()` to show that the model is working with 120 elements counted:

```
number of elements in results: 120
shape of results: (3, 40)
```

Then restart python and re-apply the model to the same corpus, without training.

```
result = apply(corpus)
print("number of elements in results: " + str(result.getnnz()))
print("shape of results: " + str(result.shape))
```

You will see that zero elements are saved this time.

```
number of elements in results: 0
shape of results: (3, 40)
```

But the model was loaded from a file *both times* and no global variables (I know of) so we can't think of why it works in one case and doesn't work in another.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I did some very deep digging and if you check the Production class [here](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/grammar.html) that you are implicitly using with the `Tree` structure, it looks like they store `_hash` when the class is created.  However the Python `hash` function is indeterministic between runs, meaning this value will probably not be consistent across runs.  Therefore the hash is pickled with `joblib` rather than being re-calculated as it should be.  So this seems like a bug in `nltk`.  This results in the model not seeing the production rule when reloaded because the hash does not match so it's as if the production rule was never stored in the vocab.

Quite tricky!

Until this specific `nltk` is fixed, setting the `PYTHONHASHSEED` before running both the training and testing scripts will force the hash to be the same each time.

```
PYTHONHASHSEED=0 python script.py
```

Comment: Creating the `sklearn...TfidfVectorizer` each time and reloading the vocabulary and weights manually before prediction didn't work - because the problematic hash is one level below in the `nltk` Tree

Comment: I made a PR: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/pull/2603

Comment: Brilliant! Your PR is a lovely true solution to this problem.